# How can I subclass AVCaptureInput and AVCaptureInput.Port?

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

The Apple docs describe AVCaptureInput as:

> AVCaptureInput is an abstract class that provides an interface for connecting capture input sources to an AVCaptureSession.

So I'm trying to inherit from it to provide a custom implementation. However, when I do, the Swift compiler tells me that `init is unavailable`, because it's private.  AVCaptureInput.Port is the same.

How can I successfully inherit from these abstract classes? This isn't being submitted to the App Store so I can use private frameworks if I have to (I'm just not sure how)